# onchage dropdown data not getting refreshed in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have following code to load data in website based on location selected, on change the ajax is getting fired and getting value in controller and from controller to model and going into where clause for sql by the result of sql is not getting showed on website.But always enters into else loop of **model**

View:

```
$(document).on('change','#delvloc',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();  // stops the jump when an anchor clicked.
      var title = this.value; // anchors do have text not values.

      $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/category/newfunc',
        data: {'title': title}, // change this to send js object
        type: "get",
        success: function(data){
           //document.write(data); just do not use document.write
           console.log(data);
        }
      });
   });
```

Controller:

```
public function newfunc(){               
           $data = array(
                    'title' => $this->request->get['title']                 
                        );  
                    $this->load->model('catalog/product');      
              $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);         


    }
```

Model:

```
    public function getProducts($data = array()) {
    $sql="SELECT p.product_id,p.city, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM monster_review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM monster_product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM monster_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special FROM monster_product p LEFT JOIN monster_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN monster_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0'"
    if (!empty($data['title'])) {
                $sql .= " and p.city='". $data['title'].  "' GROUP BY p.product_id";            
            }
    else{$sql .= " and p.city='Pune' GROUP BY p.product_id";}

}
```

My HTML:

Delivery Location:

```
            <select name="delvloc" id="delvloc" style="width: 100px;" ">
                        <?php foreach ($city as $user_group) { ?>
                        <?php if ($user_group['city'] == $user_group_id) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $user_group['user_group_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $user_group['city']; ?></option>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $user_group['city']; ?>"><?php echo $user_group['city']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                </select>
                </li>
```

Comment: Ajax URL is wrong `url: 'index.php?route=product/category/newfunc'` and **adding HTML part will be make your question nicer**.

Comment: Added my HTML above. Can you please let me know whats wrong in AJAX?

Comment: But ajax is posting the value and is fetched in controller and model as well

Comment: in controller add `print_r($data);die;` before model and post the output

Comment: I have Pune and Banglore in dropdown, on change to Pune am gettingArray
(
    [title] => Pune
)

Comment: `console.log(data);` may be print nothing is it ??

Comment: Yes console.log(data); is not printing anything

Comment: Cz in your controller there is no return

Comment: can you please suggest how do i proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

**In Model**

```
function getProducts($data) {
    $sql="SELECT p.product_id,p.city, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM monster_review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM monster_product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM monster_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special FROM monster_product p LEFT JOIN monster_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN monster_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0'"; # Mssing ; here
    if (!empty($data['title'])) 
    {
        $sql .= " and p.city='". $data['title'].  "' GROUP BY p.product_id";            
    }
    else{
        $sql .= " and p.city='Pune' GROUP BY p.product_id";
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

**In Controller**

```
function newfunc()
{  

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->request->get['title']                 
    );  

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');      
    $result = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);  

    $response['data'] = '';

    if (empty($result)) 
    {
        $response['data'] = false;
    } 
    else {
       $response['data'] = $result;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: The code you provided gives perfect output required in json format, but even though the select sql is echo perfectly  the data in the website is not getting refreshed with sql result

Comment: append it to your code. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp

Comment: ajax for? do mean i need to append the content with the query result?

Comment: what is your purpose ??

Comment: my problem is the am getting ajax value in controller, model and even the value is getting passed to sql query and sql query is built properly , but why the sql result is not get changed in website?

Comment: you need to append the result to where it to be show